# How to disable autocomplete in vba?

Tags: vba, autocomplete

I'm creating the program for exporting several excel sheets to pdf with watermarks and form fields etc. Everything works smooth right now but the final pdf is quite large. So I was thinking about the best way to make it smaller and I found out that the best result is by simply opening the pdf in Adobe Acrobat and then print it with "Adobe PDF" printer. This way I reduce the file size to 1/6 of the original size.

So I'm trying to do this via the VBA code and it looks like it's prety straight forward code using the JS.

```
sPath = "some path"
sPathFinal = "some other path"

Dim AcroApp As AcroAVDoc: Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Dim Document As AcroPDDoc
Dim JSO, pp

AcroApp.Open sPath, ""

Set Document = AcroApp.GetPDDoc()
Set JSO = Document.GetJSObject
Set pp = JSO.getPrintParams

pp.printerName = "Adobe PDF"
pp.Filename = sPathFinal

JSO.Print (pp)
```

The problem is in the very last line as it should be

JSO.print(pp) - "print" with lowercase "p"

But everytime I step away from the lane, it gets autocorrected to uppercase "P". I tried to turn everything off in Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code settings as well as on other places in options tab but had no luck so far.

Is there a way to prevent this autocorrect?

(Also I'm not native english speaking so there is quite big chance that it is called differently :)

Comment: Should it not be `JSO.Print pp`? I am not familiar with JS but I don't see why it would fall over that

Comment: According to documentation from Adobe it should be `JSO.print(pp)`. The problem seems to be that "Print" is VBA keyword so it is corrected to uppercase "Print" and therefore it brings error 438 and the JS part is not executed. Or at least I think that it is the problem.

Comment: Got it, in that case I can't help you. Hope the answer below does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answare is no you can't, because VBA editor auto-correct the case in your code.

This is because VB is **case-sensitive** (despite it doesn't look like it is), and the editor tries to prevent typo by changing the case of your variables.

If you want to preserve the case and avoid **auto-correct**, the simplest **solution** is to use another editor (like `Notepad`) and compile your code [from the command-line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/building-from-the-command-line).

Hope this help.

Comment: Thats a pitty.
Thank you for your help. I will try to make a way around :)

Comment: OK, it seems like this task is way beyond my skills. Would you mind giving me little extra help? Some useful link or some quick general instructions?